# Why are some questions grayed out in the Top Questions list?

Tags: discussion

I did try to find the answer, but couldn't:  Why are some questions "greyed out".  I can still click on them and interact normally.  I'm fairly new here so sorry if there is someplace I could have found the answer. I did look, I swear!  LOL

Update:  Here is a screen shot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: I'm not really clear about what you are asking.  Perhaps a screen image of what you are seeing.  I'm not seeing any greyed out questions.

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate this either

Comment: I use Firefox as my main browser.  I just tried it in IE and it looks fine. Must be a Firefox issue.   I thought maybe the grayed out posts had some meaning. I'll just ignore it from now on.   Thanks for looking.

Comment: Firefox is my main browser and I don't recall ever seeing anything like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you added a tag to ignore, maybe the `grounding` tag.

Here is an example of having the `plumbing` tag ignored. Questions with this tag are greyed out. Simply click the `x` next to the tag and the question should appear as normal.

[image]

Comment: You nailed it!  For some reason I had "grounding" excluded (don't remember doing that).   Interesting that it only showed correctly in FireFox and not IE.